# Favicon in IE 10 and 9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, favicon

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- favicon.ico -->
        <link ng-if="A" href="images/favicon_a.ico" rel="icon" />
        <link ng-if="B" href="images/favicon_b.ico" rel="icon" />
        <link ng-if="B" href="images/animated_favicon_b.gif" rel="icon" type="image/gif" />
     ...
    </head>
```

I want to display one icon, depending on what I have. In Chrome and Firefox everything is perfect, but in IE (even 11) I have problems:

1. `ng-if` doesn't work and I take only one icon every time
2. In IE 9 I cannot display the icon at all.

I tried everything with no results.

Any ideas?